# Xamarin - VS 2015 - looking for jdk1.7.0_71 - java.exe

Tags: java, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I have just installed Xamarin into my existing VS2015. I have a Win 7 64 bit machine. When I start a simple Xamarin.Forms project and try to build and deploy onto an Android emulator, it throws an error -
**"The specified task executable location "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin\java.exe" is invalid."**

**In Options->Xamarin->JDK Settings = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\"**

I have uninstalled JDK 1.7 from my machine, and restarted my machine. There is no difference.

I also have a 64 bit version of JDK and my JAVA_HOME points to that, which I cannot change just for Xamarin.

Where in the world is Xamarin picking up this path from?

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 13):

I had this problem too and I solved it deleting the file sdks.cache. 
You will find it in the folders OBJ (Debug or Release) and BIN (Debug or Release) of your project.
This file contains some variables configuration. This problem is because the node  is targeting to wrong path (*C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_71*).
Deleting the file is safe because it will be regenerated again with the next build but in this time will use your Xamarin configuration to set  node with the configured path.
I hope this help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when I had both versions of Java installed in my system (1.7 and 1.8). Despite Xamarin -> JDK settings pointing to 1.8 version, the error

```
specified task executable location "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin\java.exe" is invalid
```

was still displayed.

This issue can be resolved by following the steps below:

1. Uninstall Java 1.7
2. In Microsoft visual studio, click on the solution (in solution explorer) right click and select "Clean"
3. Ensure your Xamarin -> JDK settings point to Java 1.8 version
4. Rebuild the solution

Comment: Wonderful, thank you for this answer! this solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Java installed version and Xamarin referred different version .. Please config correct Java version in the Xamarin In Options->Xamarin->JDK Settings.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps I did not explain clearly. JDK installed version is jdk1.8.0_91, and JRe is jre1.8.0_91. As shown in the original message I'm pointing to this path from **Options->Xamarin->JDK Settings = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\"**

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin.Android currently [requires 32-bit Java JDK 7 (1.7)](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/manual_installation/#Requirements).  The latest version is 1.7 update 79.

> Xamarin.Android also requires that a 32-bit Java JDK 7 (1.7) be installed. Later versions of the JDK can also be installed alongside JDK 7, if required by your machine.

Comment: Thanks Trevor, I have now installed JDK jdk1.7.0_79 (32 bit) and the Options->Xamarin->JDK Settings = **"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\"**. However it still gives me the same error "The specified task executable location **"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin\java.exe"** is invalid." Looks like it is determined to look for the **update 71** of the JDK. Any idea why this is so and where Xamarin keeps this?

Comment: I am wondering if your JAVA_HOME configuration is confusing Xamarin. I'm using Visual Studio and it automatically detected the JDK 7 even after it was updated from u71 to u79. I also have JDK 8 x64 installed on the same machine.  I have not manually set JAVA_HOME.

Comment: Thanks Trevor for your prompt responses, however my JAVA_HOME points to **"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31"**. That is the 64 bit version. I hope I wont have to uninstalling and reinstalling Xamarin.